# CodePipeline unable to find the image definition file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have created a codebuild whereby the buildspec.yml is as follows (following the standard template given by AWS with minor modifications):

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)
      - REPOSITORY_URI=xxx.amazonaws.com/projectName
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=test-cicd}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building the docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:$COMMIT_HASH -t $REPOSITORY_URI:test-cicd .
      - echo Finish building the docker image.
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Pushing the docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:test-cicd
      - echo Finish pushing the docker images.
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"testcicd","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:test-cicd > imagedefinitions.json
      - cat imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

The codebuild is successfully pushing the new docker image to ECR and creating the output artifact in S3:

[image]

Next I tried to create a codepipeline in which the source is ECR and next stage is to perform codedeploy to ECS. This is the codepipeline created:
[image]
However, in the codepipeline status, it shows that the output artifact could not be found:

[image]

However, I noticed that the output artifact is indeed in S3!?

Comment: Can you downoad the artifact from s3, add "zip" extention to it, and verify its contnet?

Comment: the RepositoryName, ImageURI and ImageTags are all correct. However, the file name is imageDetail.json instead of imagedefinitions.json!? Is this the issue?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct buildspec? Also maybe your codepipline have further actions which overwrite the file?

Comment: Yes, this is the buildspec file used. I added a screenshot of the codepipeline, it has only 2 stages -> Source & Deploy

Comment: Where is your CodeBuild stage?

Comment: CodeBuild is separate from pipeline now

Comment: Sorry, I don't understend your setup. So how would Deploy stage be synchronized with that? It uses different artifact from what i see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234275/discussion-between-user990639-and-marcin).

Comment: The only logical explanation I can think of is the OutputArtifact from the stage that runs the codebuild project and produces the imagedefinitions.json is not an InputArtifact tot he stage that runs CodeDeploy

Comment: any updates im stuck in the exact same step. My file is impeccable, and it's located in the "root" (it's literaly the only file in the atrifact) and i get the same error